# XML - adding new line

Tags: xml, ms-word, docx

I have MS word doc saved as `.docx`. I want to insert new line in my text by edditing XML file of docx. I have already tried `&#xA;`, `&#13;`, `&#10;`, `&#x9;`, amd it always gives me only space not a new line.

what it does:

(XML code)
`<w:t>hel&#xA;lo</w:t>`

When I open `.docx` file then it is changed to:

`Hel lo` not as I wanted to be `Hel` on one line and `lo` on secound line.

Comment: have you tried doing the edit in word, and examine the differences?

Comment: Yes I have it does something like <w:p>… but I need to use code for new line character, because I will be loading data from DB and all name I will load want to have each one on new line ... I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Are you really editing .docx files? How? (They are not XML as such, but zipped XML.)

Comment: What I am doing is changing .docx to .zip to acces document.xml and that is place where I am changing it ... yes zipped XML ... any solution?

Comment: Jukka's approach was what I was hinting at, but I did not have access to a Word installation to do it myself

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `<w:br/>` tag.

I found it by creating a Word document, saving it as XML (via Save As), adding a forced line break with Shift Enter, and checked out the change. The essential difference seems to be just the `w:br` tag, apparently reflecting the HTML `br` tag.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time! Thx for answer!

Comment: Might seem obvious but what actually needs to be done is replacing the `<w:t></w:t>` tag all together with `<w:br/>`...

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone, the following bit of c# code will create the multi-line XML structure

```
//Sets the text for a Word XML <w:t> node
//If the text is multi-line, it replaces the single <w:t> node for multiple nodes
//Resulting in multiple Word XML lines
private static void SetWordXmlNodeText(XmlDocument xmlDocument, XmlNode node, string newText)
{

    //Is the text a single line or multiple lines?>
    if (newText.Contains(System.Environment.NewLine))
    {
        //The new text is a multi-line string, split it to individual lines
        var lines = newText.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        //And add XML nodes for each line so that Word XML will accept the new lines
        var xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int count = 0; count < lines.Length; count++)
        {
            //Ensure the "w" prefix is set correctly, otherwise docFrag.InnerXml will fail with exception
            xmlBuilder.Append("<w:t xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml\">");
            xmlBuilder.Append(lines[count]);
            xmlBuilder.Append("</w:t>");

            //Not the last line? add line break
            if (count != lines.Length - 1)
            {
                xmlBuilder.Append("<w:br xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml\" />");
            }
        }

        //Create the XML fragment with the new multiline structure
        var docFrag = xmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment();
        docFrag.InnerXml = xmlBuilder.ToString();
        node.ParentNode.AppendChild(docFrag);

        //Remove the single line child node that was originally holding the single line text, only required if there was a node there to start with
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }
    else
    {
        //Text is not multi-line, let the existing node have the text
        node.InnerText = newText;
    }
}
```

The code above will create the necessary child nodes and carriage returns, and takes care of the prefix as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Lenny's answer above, this is what works using Obj-C in my situation with MS Word 2011 on a Mac:

```
- (NSString *)setWordXMLText:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *newStr = @"";
    // split the string into individual lines
    NSArray *lines = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];

    if (lines.count > 1)
    {
        // add XML nodes for each line so that Word XML will accept the new lines
        for (int count = 0; count < lines.count; count++)
        {
            newStr = [newStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"<w:t>%@</w:t>", lines[count]];

            // Not the last line? add a line break
            if (count != lines.count - 1)
            {
                newStr = [newStr stringByAppendingString:@"<w:br/>"];
            }
        }

        return newStr;
    }
    else
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```