# Using XSLT and WordML - new line character

Tags: xslt, wordml

I am using XSLT to create a Word Document using WordML. I have most of what I need, except the newline characters which come out of the database as \r\n

I can change these to whatever is required, but I cannot find out what to change them to. What character should I change them to please so newlines appear in the resulting Word document.

Many thanks

Comment: What are you doing with them? Creating new paragraphs? Then you must interpret them to a new XML structure (like w:p). Or possibly you are looking for <w:br/> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [XML - adding new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270600/xml-adding-new-line)

This gives a complete answer to your question. What you do is based on what you need to do ... simply insert a w:br or adding new structure like adding multiple w:p elements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above I tend to put `<w:tab/>` before the `<w:br/>` in the separate run. The reason for that is if the text is fully justified and you don't add the tab it will add a lot of spacing between the words in a line if there are only few words on that line.

```
<w:r> <w:tab/> </w:r> <w:r> <w:br/> </w:r>
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably will want to add a new w:p element, because the w:br approach adds a "manual line break" (which will have different searching behavior).